# Iterate JSON array with maps using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is the JSON array i am receiving from the dynamo DB and i need to iterate the same display the results in a table. where M is Map with more than one values. Can any one help me with the Jquery and HTML part of it.

```
{
    "Item": {
        "Subscriptions": {
            "M": {}
        },
        "NetworkID": {
            "S": "1234"
        },
        "SubscriptionARNs": {
            "SS": [
                " "
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "need to iterate the same display the results in a table"?

Comment: The only array there is `SS`.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear about my desciption. I basically want to iterate the JSON array [Item] and populate it in a HTML table/div.

Comment: Do you want just these 3 pieces of data in an html table, or are you going to get multiple results?  If so, what will those results look like, and how do you want your table to look? What should the table headers be?

Comment: It will be always 3 pieces of data in the JSON which needs to be populated in HTML. There will not be any change in the response. Only the values inside the Subscriptions  map can vary. The below format is what i need.                                                                                                  NetworkID : Subscriptions: SubscriptionARNs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is all the data in details you can do what you want to do with it, first one deal with it as a hash, second as a string, third as an array:

```
data = {....}
item = data["Item"]

Subscriptions =  item["Subscriptions"]
NetworkID =  item["NetworkID"]
SubscriptionARNs =  item["SubscriptionARNs"]

// for Subscriptions Data
M = Subscriptions["M"]
keys = Object.keys(M)
for(i = 0;i<keys.length;i++){
  console.log(keys[i] +"="+M[keys[i]])
 }

// for Network Data
S = NetworkID["S"]

// for SubscriptionARNs Data
SS = SubscriptionARNs["SS"]
for(i = 0;i<SS.length;i++){
  console.log(SS[i])  
}
```